# Text imported from realm DB not clickable

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm helping to build an app which ask you a series of questions and returns the appropriate stone (geological app). The app also has an encyclopedia and a guide.

There are link to explanations in the guide when asking questions and these work fine. 
The problem occurs when I want to use the links in the guide itself.
The guide uses a Realm DB for the info and puts it in an expandable list, while the questions use a string resource.

I want to be able to use the link in the text that I put in the Realm DB, but currently it just prints it as a normal string like so

```
".. ali več različnih <a href="com.malasola://ZRNA">  mineralnih zrn </a>, nekatere ..."
```

This is the same code that works fine in the questions section. 
The code I use to "try" and convert the strings to links from the DB is bellow.

```
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.kamnina_item_second, null);
TextView opis = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opis_kamnine);
String stone_opis_string = expandableListDetail.get("OPIS_POJMA").get(0);
opis.setText(stone_opis_string);
Linkify.addLinks(opis,Linkify.ALL);
opis.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
String stone_opis_string = expandableListDetail.get("OPIS_POJMA").get(0);
opis.setText(Html.fromHtml(stone_opis_string));
// Linkify.addLinks(opis,Linkify.ALL);
opis.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```